# Ajax call does not work, when call the Web Api Get Method. Have you know, what i missed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I Have a get method in `ValuesController` in Server side, here am using MVC 4 Web  Api

The Method

```
[HttpGet]
        public List<Product> Get()
        {
            return productRepository.ListOfProducts().ToList();
        }
```

and i have call this method via ajax

```
$.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:57260/api/values",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Ramesh is a yummy ;)");
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    $("<tr></tr><td></td>" + data[i].Name + "</td><td></td>" + data[i].Address + "</td><td></td>" + data[i].DOB + "</td></tr>").appendTo("#tbPerson");
                }
            },
            error: function (msg) {
                alert("Ramesh is a fool");
            }
        });
```

> This ajax method always go to failure function, does not go to success method

But when i type the url in browser, then it's return json data. See this screen..

[image]

BUT Why ajax does not work? It's very strange...

Regard's, Ramesh.

### Update :

**I can't see console error details, because am using window mobile app, So it's running on the mobile emulator**

Comment: Check any error in firebug

Comment: any errors in web browser console(check firebug)

Comment: @Rex  I can't see console, because am using window mobile app, Sop it's running on the mobile emulator

Comment: I will check it using fiddler, please wait a mins

Comment: Oops, Guy's i can't , because fiddler does not get the emulator process :(

Comment: @RameshRajendran, actually, you can use Fiddler to monitor traffic from mobile device. For this you need to enable remote connections in fiddler and set up Fiddler on your computer as proxy on mobile device. BTW, is this endpoint under authorization?

Comment: URL is thrown the error, It's shown wrong url .. @YuriyRozhovetskiy

Comment: @RameshRajendran which url? If u  tried to set Fiddler as proxy, consider to open 8888(by default Fiddler use) port in firewall

Comment: @YuriyRozhovetskiy , when i use this `error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert(xhr.statusText + " - " + xhr.status + "\n\n" + xhr.responseText);
        }` , now it's get `error,0 ` am really confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is mostly likely because of same-origin policy restriction as far as I can understand from the details you have given. Google for "ASP.NET Web API CORS".

Answer (score 0):

This will work.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:57260/api/values",
    method: "GET",
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
    function (data) {
        alert("Ramesh is a yummy ;)");
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            $("<tr></tr><td></td>" + data[i].Name + "</td><td></td>" + data[i].Address + "</td><td></td>" + data[i].DOB + "</td></tr>").appendTo("#tbPerson");
        }
    },
    error: function (msg) {
        alert("Ramesh is a fool");
    }
});
```